# Get variable value by manifest in pivotal

Tags: cloud-foundry

I needed to change the actuator management port. With this I need to explicit the port in the check request url of the health check of pitoval. With this, I have my application running on port 8080 and my actuator on port 8091. How to explicitly in the url port that health check should make the request?

I'm trying to do so in the manifest.yml:

```
health-check-type: http
health-check-http-endpoint: ${CF_INSTANCE_IP}:8091/actuator/health
```

However, this approach does not work

Comment: Have you tried by adding ${CF_INSTANCE_IP} in application.properties file?

Comment: @KumareshBabu how would that help me if i need ip while the app is still uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a port into the health check entry point.  The `health-check-http-endpoint` property takes an endpoint (i.e. the path part of a URL, not a full URL).

The error you get if you try to set the health check endpoint to a full URL confirms this:

```
{
   "description": "The app is invalid: health_check_http_endpoint HTTP health check endpoint is not a valid URI path: http://www.google.com/",
   "error_code": "CF-AppInvalid",
   "code": 100001
}
```

It's looking for a **URI Path** [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax).  Example acceptable values: "/", "/health", "/info", etc..

You can also see this point [in the code](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/healthcheck/blob/2c8e6a82b7584d6dcfd9a81fcc01947a59fa62d5/cmd/healthcheck/main_external_port.go#L19-L31) where the healthcheck is loading the port from the `CF_INSTANCE_PORTS` env variable.